# Can't cast MySQLDataSource to java.sql.driver

Tags: java, mysql, hikaricp

In this Java project, I wanted to try working with HikariCP for one, see if I would like it.

It seems very simple at first, but when I actually try to run my application, it goes wrong. The following code is a function in my `DatabasePool.java`

```
    HikariConfig configuration = new HikariConfig();
    configuration.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb");
    configuration.addDataSourceProperty("serverName","127.0.0.1");
    configuration.addDataSourceProperty("port", 3306);
    configuration.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", "testdb"));
    configuration.addDataSourceProperty("user", "root");
    configuration.addDataSourceProperty("password", "123");
    configuration.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource");
    this.database = new HikariDataSource(configuration);
    return true;
```

And for some reason, when this gets ran, I get the following error back:

```
[main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-0 - is starting.
[main] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource was not found, trying direct instantiation.
[main] WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Could not instantiate instance of driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource, trying JDBC URL resolution
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource cannot be cast to java.sql.Driver
```

I checked if the class exists in my project, it does. I can't really think of a cause for this.

I'm new to pretty new to Java, so I have no idea if I supplied enough information in the question. Please state it if that's not the case.

Comment: A `DataSource` is not a `Driver`. Use `setDataSourceClassName()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DataSource` is not a `Driver`. Use setDataSourceClassName() instead (I seem to remember it being recommended over `setDriverClassName()` anyway).

Answer (score 0):

```
import ru.steklopod.repositories.ConnectionAccesNamesStore._
  def init(): Unit = {
    val dataSource: DataSource = {
      val ds = new HikariDataSource()
      ds.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_MARIA_DB)
      ds.setJdbcUrl(URL_MARIA)
      ds.setPassword(PSWRD_MARIA)
      ds.setUsername(LOGIN_MARIA)
      ds
    }
    ConnectionPool.singleton(new DataSourceConnectionPool(dataSource))
  }

object ConnectionAccesNamesStore {
currentSchema=" + SHEMA_NAME
  val URL_MARIA = "jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
  val DRIVER_MARIA_DB = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
  var LOGIN_MARIA = "root"
  val PSWRD_MARIA = "root"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below configuration in the **spring boot** application using YAML configuration in application.yml.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
    username: root
    password: root
```